# How to memoise a function at package startup in R

Tags: r, r-package, memoise

I work on an R package which wraps API calls. In order to reduce the number of actual calls and to speed things up, I memoise the function making the API call. To do so, I created the following function, which allows to set the cache directory:

```
memoise_fromJSON <- function(cache_dir = tempdir()) {
  memoise::memoise(jsonlite::fromJSON,
                   cache = memoise::cache_filesystem(cache_dir))
}
```

To create the memoised function I use

```
memoised_fromJSON <- memoise_fromJSON()
```

Now, since I need the memoised function many times within my package, I would like to memoise the function at package startup. I tried

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  memoised_fromJSON <- my_package:::memoise_fromJSON()
}
```

but I still need to run `memoised_fromJSON <- memoise_fromJSON()` to get it to work.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a possibility to memoise a function at package startup?
2. If so, how can I memoise the function in a way that it is not visible in the global environment?

I guess, the questions are somehow related. Is my understanding correct that my attempt with `.onLoad()` does not work because it creates the memoised function within the environment of `.onLoad()`?

---

PS: I am aware, that I cannot change the `cache_dir` at package loading, but I want to set a reasonable default which makes it possible to start without further ado. However, this keeps the possibility to change the cache directory if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You are performing a *local* assignment inside the `onLoad` function.

And you cannot simply perform a (package-) global assignment, since the package namespace is locked. What you *can* do is

1. Create a new environment via `new.env(parent = parent.env(environment())` (the parameter ensures that this environment finds objects defined inside your package namespace).
2. Assign the memoised functions inside that environment.
3. `attach` the environment. Now, this is generally frowned upon and will in fact earn you a red card from CRAN if you attempt to submit it. In fact, your `.onLoad` function *mustn’t* call `attach` since a user might want to use your package without attaching it. But I think it’s legitimate if you do this in `.onAttach` rather than `.onLoad`. The CRAN maintainers might not agree though, I’m afraid; then again, there’s precedence for CRAN packages that call `attach` under specific circumstances, e.g. {devtools}.

Answer (score 0):

And why not directly declare the memoised function in your R sources ?

```r
#' Memoised version of [jsonlite::fromJSON]
#' @inherit jsonlite::fromJSON
#' 
#' @export
memoised_fromJSON <- memoise::memoise(jsonlite::fromJSON,
                                      cache = memoise::cache_filesystem(tempdir()))
```

That should do the job without any notes or warnings in R CMD check.